# Azure Storage - 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am getting 403 forbidden error message while connecting to azure storage from application server. I am using below code snippet to check connectivity with azure storage.

I am not sure it could be our firewall/proxy not allowing connectivity or related to SSL certificate (cert revocation). I am checking with our network team on this; any suggestion would be helpful.

```
  string storageConnString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=azstoragel692;AccountKey=asdfas234234sdfsdf234234;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";   
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnString);
        var blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("myContainer");
        var blobsCount = container.ListBlobs().Count();
        Console.WriteLine(blobsCount);
```

Exception:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an e
>   rror: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (403) Forbidden.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTC
>   ommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Prog
>   ram Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\C
>   ore\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677
>
> Request Information
>   RequestID:
>   RequestDate:Fri, 01 Dec 2017 14:04:26 GMT
>   StatusMessage:AccessDenied

Comment: Have you double-checked the account name and key?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sorry I should have mentioned it in my question itself. The account name and key mentioned in code snippet are dummy. Though I am sure that I am using correct account name and key for my connectivity test.

Comment: I also try same code snippet with _DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http_ and getting same error.

Comment: Have you tried to use another storage account and key? The code you mentioned works correctly on myside. Have you tried to update the [Azure storeage SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) version to 8.6.0? Addtional info: The container name shoud be lower case.

Comment: Thanks @TomSun for the response. I tried with other storage account and key as well, getting same error. Also I am using Azure Storage SDK 8.6.0. Container name is lower case in my original code.

Comment: Please have a try to use fiddler to catch the http request sent by Azure storage SDK to get more exception about that.

Comment: If it is possible, please add the screenshot of  http request sent by the azure storage SDK.

Comment: I'm able to run your code without issue, except... your example container name (`myContainer`) would never work, since container names must be all lower-case. Using my own connection string and valid container name, and Azure Storage 8.6.0, this code runs fine for me unchanged. This leads me to believe you have some type of networking issue, and that it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue. It was with our enterprise proxy which was blocking the connection to Azure storage account. As I was trying to connect Azure blob storage so we had to whitelist URL ***.blob.core.windows.net** on the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is the answer for your case but it may be the answer for someone else.

In my case, I was getting `403 Forbidden` because the server was somehow set to an hour before.

This was followed by an issue with the data center. I can't be sure if this was the cause but the fact is that after I synced the time correctly, it started working just fine.

I got this tip (request timestamp too old) after installing `Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer` in the server and trying to access the blob storage.

Comment: can u explain what exactly was synched? What 2 components had to be synched?

Comment: The time of the client and server. The server checks if the request received was created very recently. So the clock of both client and server need to be up to date and that's what needs to be synced.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the clock on the servers in question. Apart from the incorrect account key, you can also get 403 error if the time on the server is not in sync with the time on storage servers (Give or take +/- 15 minutes deviation is allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to leave this here for anyone else experiencing the issue... it could be the sas key is expired or doesn't have adequate permissions. I was able to resolve the issue myself by creating a new sas key with the permissions I needed.